# How to get element in template html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing an `Electron` app, in which the `index.html` imports a `search.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="search.html">
```

And inside the `search.html`, I create a button whose id is `searchBtn`.

Then, in the `redenerer.js`, I try to get the `searchBtn`:

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"][href="search.html"]');
var content = link.import.querySelector('template');
console.log(content);
var searchBtn = content.querySelector('#searchBtn');  
console.log(searchBtn);
```

The output of the first log is expected, but the second log for `searchBtn` is always **null**.

Is there any wrong with my code? If so, how to obtain the element in template html correctly?

The output is following:

[image]

I notice that there is a `document-fragment` inside the template.

Comment: The log shows that the `content` is the `template`, in which there is a `document-fragment`.

Comment: Can you set up a demo page? maybe on codepen?

Comment: Might be helpful https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Answer (score 5):

Run the `querySelector` function on the templates `content` property.

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"][href="search.html"]');
var templateContent = link.import.querySelector('template');
console.log(templateContent);
var searchBtn = templateContent.content.querySelector('#searchBtn');  
console.log(searchBtn);
```

More about [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

More about [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y467jjqoj);

Comment: It works now. It seems that the we should access the document fragment via `content` property.

Comment: I now have problems with the event binding: [how-to-bind-the-event-in-html-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273505/how-to-bind-the-event-in-html-template)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
// parse you HTML first
var html = link.import.querySelector('template');
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html.content, "application/xml");

//later
var searchBtn = doc.querySelector('#searchBtn');  
console.log(searchBtn);
```

Comment: the `doc` is empty.