# How to bind the event in html template?

Tags: javascript, html

Please refer to my previous question: [How to get element in template html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264322/how-to-get-element-in-template-html).

Firstly, I follow the solution in [How to get element in template html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264322/how-to-get-element-in-template-html) to obtain the element.

```
var template = templateContent.content;
```

Then I try to bind a `click` event for `searchBtn`:

```
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('click'); // does not work
});
```

This binding fails, so I use the event delegation to handle event:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'searchBtn'){
        console.log('click');
        console.log(template.querySelector('#results'));
        template.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'Foo';
    }
 });
```

The two logs are expected, but the last command to update the `innerText` does not work. On the other hand, I can update its content outside the click event. Any solution?

The final version of my code:

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"][href="search.html"]');
var templateContent = link.import.querySelector('template');
var template = templateContent.content;
var searchBtn = template.querySelector('#searchBtn'); 
console.log(searchBtn); 
template.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'Bar'; // ok

document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'searchBtn'){
        console.log('click'); // ok
        console.log(template.querySelector('#results')); // ok
        template.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'Foo'; // does not work
    }
 });
```

### Updates

Now I retrieve the `results` element outside the function:

```
var results = template.querySelector('#results');
```

Then inside the function, `results.innerText = 'Foo';` works. However, this only updates the `results` itself, and the UI is not updated correspondingly.

How to update the UI inside the template?

Comment: What do you mean by 'However, this only updates the results itself, and the UI is not updated correspondingly' ? what is exactly not working here? Have you tried with binding this here as described in answer?

Comment: this might be useful https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: @NarendraMongiya I log the `results.innerText` inside the click function, and it is updated. But the nothing happens in the UI.

Comment: yes, because that is inside the scope of function.

Comment: but template does not have any reference inside eventlisterner without binding. The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Comment: so, how to update the UI inside this bind event?

Comment: as in the answer you need to pas this (onClick.bind(this)) and in function this.template.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'Foo';

Comment: in my case, `this.template` is undefined after passing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183537/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-chenzhongpu).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding event listener on a dom element inside template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387346/adding-event-listener-on-a-dom-element-inside-template-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You got it right, it is the binding issue. **template** is not available inside click function. You need to bind this. There are many ways to do this e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('click',onClick.bind(this));


 onClick = function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'searchBtn'){
        console.log('click'); // ok
        console.log(template.querySelector('#results')); // ok
        this.template.querySelector('#results').innerText = 'Foo'; // should work
    }
 }
```

Comment: double functions?

Comment: Please see my updated question. The `results` value is updated, but the UI remains unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to get the HTML elements

You can get use

```
var sbtnElement = document.getElementById('searchBtn');
```

then add eventlistener to it

```
sbtnElement.addEventlistener('click', function() {
   console.log('click'); // does not work
});
```

Naturally getElement by id will give you one element, and getElementsByClassName will return you an array of elements with the same classname. Same goes for getElementsByTagName.

Comment: You may refer to my previous question: [How to get element in template html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264322/how-to-get-element-in-template-html). I have to access the element in a template html.

Answer (score -2):

hi i don't know what are you try to create for. but have you ever try to use template in script ? like this one

```
<script id="sampleTemplate" type="text/template">
   // do the html here
</script>
```

So in that case you can bind event using that one. just a normal creating of html and binding javascript function.

You can refer to this blog. https://jonsuh.com/blog/javascript-templating-without-a-library/

I hope, i helped you thru this. :)

Comment: You may refer to my previous question [How to get element in template html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264322/how-to-get-element-in-template-html). Now I can access the element, but there are some problems with the event bindings.